# Use Diff to check changed files in folder structure ignoring lines starting with pattern

Tags: linux, diff

Have been trying below in order to find changes to files in a Magento installation:

```
diff --exclude="cache" --exclude="session" --exclude="tmp" --ignore-matching-lines='\*.+' -urq /folder/modified /folder/original > diff.txt
```

The problem is really the ignore statement that doesn't work at all. The headers of the files in one folder contains:

```
* @copyright   Copyright (c) 2012 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
```

and the other

```
* @copyright   Copyright (c) 2010 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
```

I would prefer to target these lines only but any comment will do really.

Comment: Glad you're having to deal with my same issues on the same product. There seems to be some way to `git diff -G"^\s * @copyright" -w HEAD^ HEAD` after an update, but that doesn't work as expected. We should complain about such garbage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A working solution :

```
diff --exclude="cache" --exclude="session" --exclude="tmp" --ignore-matching-lines='copyright *Copyright.*Magento' -urq dir1 dir2
```

regex simply modified.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of Magento, the copyright line has changed slightly to:

`* @copyright  Copyright (c) 2006-2017 X.commerce, Inc. and affiliates (http://www.magento.com)`

So I now use this diff command:

`diff -r --exclude="var" --exclude="downloader" --ignore-matching-lines='copyright' 1.9.3.3 1.9.3.1`

Tip: You can also pipe this output into `colordiff` to colorize it, or `diffstat` to summarize it.